# Running logistic model using mapply in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mapply

I'm having the following function:

```
logModels <- function(data_idx_list,data)   

{
  x  <-  lapply(data_idx_list, function(m) 
        sparse.model.matrix(~.,data = data[m,]))
  y <- lapply(data_idx_list, function(m) data$earlyR[m])

  logM <- mapply(function(x,y) {
          cv.glmnet(x=x,y=y,family="binomial",alpha=0)
}, x,y) 

return(logM)

}
```

where `x` contains 5 samples of data, and `y` is my *dependent variable*. When I'm trying to use `mapply` I'm getting the following error:

> Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda,  : 
>     number of observations in y (1) not equal to the number of rows of x (100000)

But, when I'm running the model as follows it works:

```
lm1 = cv.glmnet(x=x[[1]],y=y,family="binomial",alpha=0)
```

So, I assume I have some trouble with the way I'm approaching `x` in my `mapply` function.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you simply need to wrap `y` into a `list`:

```
logM <- mapply(function(x, y) cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 0),
               x, list(y))
```

Otherwise individual elements of `y` are passed to consecutive invocations of your glm function.

Another, more concise way of writing this:

```
logM <- mapply(cv.glmnet, x = x, y = list(y), family = "binomial", alpha = 0))
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.. but, for some reason it doesn't work.. I tried to use your syntax, and I'm getting the following error: _Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda,  : 
  number of observations in y (5) not equal to the number of rows of x (100000)_ (I also tried to use `x=list(x)` instead, and I'm getting the following error: _Error in rep(1, N) : invalid 'times' argument_). I believe it somehow connected to the _indexing_ part. For example, when I'm running it using a loop, `logM2[[i]] = cv.glmnet(x=x[[i]],y=y[[i]],family="binomial",alpha=0)` it works